# How to add custom font in gwt rich editor material

Tags: gwt, material-design, rich-text-editor

Currently only four fonts are visible in font family drop down.I have to add font calibri font,lato to the respective drop down.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: GWT or smartGWT's RichTextEditor?

Comment: its  RichTextEditor

Answer (score 0):

The only Rich Text editor I've managed to get properly working is the one from the smartGWT library. It's not a great editor either but does work.

Here's how to set the fonts, the background colour as well as the widget controls:

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.RichTextEditor;

final RichTextEditor rte = new RichTextEditor();
rte.setSize("700px", "400px");
rte.setValue(callback.getRichTextHtml(html.name)); // the html content
rte.setControlGroups(new String[]{"fontControls", "styleControls", "formatControls", "colorControls", "bulletControls"});
rte.setEditAreaBackgroundColor(ArgbToHex(html.a, html.r, html.g, html.b)); // html string value

LinkedHashMap<String, String> fonts = new LinkedHashMap<>();
fonts.put("FreeSans", "Sans"); // put your fonts here
fonts.put("FreeSerif", "Serif");
fonts.put("FreeMono", "Mono");
rte.setFontNames(fonts);
```